# Android AWS Security Credential Issue

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, credentials

I am having a problem integrating the AmazonS3PersonalFileStore demo app login into my App

I have set up my TVM and everything works fine on the demo app, it also runs correctly when I copy/paste the project and rename it.

The issue comes when I begin pasting my .javas from my main app into the pasted Demo app, now when I login, I get the error

Credential Problem!
AWS Credentials not configured correctly.  Please review the README file.

the readme refers to project setup and the .properties file, all of which I did not touch

Here is my manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.amazonaws.demo.personalfilestore"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".S3PersonalFileStore"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Login"></activity>        

    <activity android:name=".s3.S3BucketView"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".s3.S3ObjectView"></activity>   
    <activity android:name=".s3.S3AddObjectView"></activity>
    <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.example.indrive.MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/main_menu" />
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.example.indrive.TripMain"
            android:label="@string/trips"/>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.example.indrive.TripView"
            android:label="@string/trip_view"/>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.example.indrive.DiagnosticsMain"
            android:label="@string/diagnostics"/>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.example.indrive.DtcListView"
            android:label="@string/dtcs"/>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.example.indrive.RpmComparison"
            android:label="@string/rpm_distribution"/>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.example.indrive.UbiMain"
            android:label="@string/ubi"/>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.example.indrive.UbiView"
            android:label="@string/ubi_view"/>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.example.indrive.UsageMain"
            android:label="@string/usage"/>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.example.indrive.EnvironmentalMain"
            android:label="@string/environmental_main"/>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.example.indrive.ComparisonMain"
            android:label="@string/vehicle_comparison"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxxxxxx"/>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Although I have added new code, I am pretty sure that none of it is running, since none of my activities are being created

Update: I tried adding an EC2 role to the TVM Elastic Beanstalk with the same permissions as the IAM TVMUser, but the demo app wouldn't even work

Update 2: Tried a bunch of different IAM configurations for the TVM IAM User / Elastic Beanstalk, nothing worked

Comment: what do you see when you go to your TVM instance at `instancename.elasticbeanstalk.com`

Comment: On my pc: Congratulations!
Token Vending Machine is running with Identity registration.
Warning: You are not running SSL.

on my phone: I can register with a username/password

Comment: does your TVM.json credentials match your IAM user credentials?

Comment: I have the same access key in my IAM TVMUser & Elastic Beanstalk TVM Environment Properties if that's what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when integrating the AmazonS3PersonalFileStore demo app login into my app.

The problem was that the request to the TVM via the HTTP request was blocked. This is due to the android sdk's StrictMode.ThreadPolicy which does not allow network operations to execute on the UI thread.

This restriction can be changed, using:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

Add the above code into your main activity's onCreate() method.

**In addition, it is always recommended to move network operation off the UI thread, for example, using AsyncTask.**

I am confident this will fix your problem.